# SqlBulkCopy failing when trying to handle more than 1 row

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to perform a bulk upload operation to a SQL Server database. I'm working in .NET 7, and I'm using a `SqlBulkCopy` instance to upload my data as a `DataTable`.

I've had all sorts of issues getting it to work at all, mostly relating to the types of the fields I'm sending, but I'm at a point now that data will upload, but only if there's a single row in the `DataTable`. I can skip around in my enumerable of data, and no matter what I do, it works with a single row, but fails with 2 or more.

The error message from the operation simply says

> The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination

but without telling me which `ColumnMapping`.

I've tried changing the types multiple times, to make sure they match the DB types. The column mappings is a new addition after I found an article on the internet, but that doesn't seem to make a difference with this issue. I've tried inserting different rows from my dataset, but the behaviour is consistent - 1 row works, multiple rows fail.  I'm honestly not sure what else to try at this point!

This is my code to convert to `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var columns = props.Select(x =>
            x switch
            {
                { PropertyType.Name: "Nullable`1" } pi => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(x.PropertyType).Map(y =>
                {
                    var c = new DataColumn(pi.Name, y);
                    c.AllowDBNull = true;
                    return c;
                }),
                not null => new DataColumn(x.Name, x.PropertyType)
            }).ToArray();

    tb.Columns.AddRange(columns);
        
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var r = tb.NewRow();

        foreach (var c in columns)
        {
            var value = (typeof(T).GetProperty(c.ColumnName)?.GetValue(item)) ?? DBNull.Value;
            r[c.ColumnName] = value;
        }

        tb.Rows.Add(r);
    }

    return tb;
}
```

And this is my code for performing the bulk insert after it:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

using var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(this.dbConnectionString);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table;

foreach (DataRow r in data.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in data.Columns)
    {
        // N.B - the column names of my class are the same as the Db columns
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);
    }
 }

 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
```

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could point me to where it is I've gone wrong. This issue has taken up far more time than it really has any right to!

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: What does your `DataTable data` look like in the VS Debugger DataTable Visualizer right before you call `ulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);` ?

Comment: Where do I find the DataTable visualliser?  I'd just been playing around with StringBuilders to get descriptions of it

Comment: Are you sure you need to wrap a loop for rows around your column loop? Because if you have n rows, then you will map all the columns n times instead of once. Is this really necessary?

Comment: Do you have a primary key?  Insert will only add row if the primary key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```cs
foreach (DataRow r in data.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in data.Columns)
    {
        // N.B - the column names of my class are the same as the Db columns
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);
    }
}
```

Your code is adding **new** `ColumnMapping` entries for all columns *for every row* in the table - so if your `DataTable` has 10 columns and 500 rows then you're instructing `SqlBulkCopy` that you've got 5,000 columns to map, with 99.9% of them sharing identical names - hence why `SqlBulkCopy` complained about *"The given `ColumnMapping` does not match up with any column in the source or destination"* (though that error is likely caused by an initial `c.ColumnName` not matching-up exactly with your source or destination tables).

Change your code to this:

```cs
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>( IEnumerable<T> items )
{
    ( DataColumn c, PropertyInfo pi )[] columns = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
        .Select( pi =>
        {
            if( Nullable.GetUnderlyingType( pi.PropertyType ) is nullableUnderlyingType )
            {
                return ( c: new DataColumn( pi.Name, nullableUnderlyingType ) { AllowDBNull = true }, pi );
            }
            else
            {
                return ( c: new DataColumn( pi.Name, pi.PropertyType ), pi );
            }
        } )
        .ToArray();

    DataTable tb = new DataTable( typeof(T).Name );
    foreach( ( DataColumn c, _ ) in columns )
    {
        tb.Columns.Add( c );
    }

    foreach( T item in items )
    {
        DataRow row = tb.NewRow();

        foreach( ( DataColumn c, PropertyInfo pi ) in columns )
        {
            Object value = pi.GetValue( item ) ?? DBNull.Value;
            row[c] = value;
        }

        tb.Rows.Add( row );
    }

    return tb;
}

public static async Task ImportAsync( IEnumerable<T> items, SqlConnection c, String destTableName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
{
    DataTable table = ToDataTable( items );

    using SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy( c );
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName;

    foreach( DataColumn c in table.Columns )
    {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add( c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName );
    }

    await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync( table, cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dai - that's absolutely spot on.  It had obviously been a long day, and my mistake was obvious once you pointed it out!